# Eject on menu bar shows "No Drives" even though an external drive is connected

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, menu-bar, eject

I have an external drive connected to my mac and I'm able to eject it from the finder window or the desktop like usual.

Finder:

[image: finder]

Desktop:

[image: Desktop]

But, I would like to be able to eject it from a menu bar icon. So, I did a little research and found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/138749/remove-eject-icon-from-menu-bar) post that let me add an *Eject Menu* to the menu bar. But, now the thing is it's not showing my connected external drives defeating the whole purpose. There is just an eject icon sitting on the menu bar when clicked upon shows "No Drives" even when an external drive is connected.

Menu Bar:

[image: menu bar]

Is there a way for me to make my external drive show up on the menu bar?

Comment: Let me know if I've missed any details.

Comment: Have you tried ejecting it (using the sidebar) and simply plugging it back in so all the services can refresh?

Comment: @Allan Already did that. But, still didn't show up.

Comment: As far as I know that eject icon is and was for *optical* drives (CD/DVD/Etc.). Never seen it used for any other kind of drive.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar and came across this article [How to Quickly Unmount External Drives From the macOS Menu Bar](https://www.howtogeek.com/308929/how-to-quickly-unmount-external-drives-from-the-macos-menu-bar/) for an app called [Semulov](https://www.kainjow.com/).

[image]
Works as advertised.